# how do I get rid of selected words from a string

Tags: javascript, html

how do I get rid of selected words from a string
this is what ive tried

```
<html>
<body>
<p align="center"><input type="text" id="myText" 
 placeholder="Definition"></p>
<p align="center"><button class="button-three" onclick="BoiFunction()"><p 
 align="center">boii         </p></button></p>
 <font color="black"><p align="center" id="demo"></p></font> 
 </body>
</html>


function BoiFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("myText").value; 
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var GarbageWords = str.split(",").split("by");
output.innerHTML = GarbageWords;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "selected words?"

Comment: like any words that I don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.split()`, you can just use `.replace()` with a regular expression.

```js
// ", " and " by " are to be removed from the string
var str = "A string, that by has, some by bad words in, by it."; 
// Replace ", " globally in the string with just " "
// and replace " by " globally in the string with just " "
str = str.replace(/,\s/g," ").replace(/\sby\s/g," ");
console.log(str);
```

Or, for a more automated version:

```js
// Array to hold bad words
var badWords = [",", "by", "#"];

var str = "A string, that by has, #some# by bad words in, by it."; 

// Loop through the array and remove each bad word
badWords.forEach(function(word){
  var reg = new RegExp(word, "g");
  var replace = (word === "," || word === "by") ? " " : "";
  str = str.replace(reg, replace);
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: I would like to have just plain javascript

Comment: @JoseSalgado Both of these solutions are plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of unwanted words you can use `string#replace` and `regex`. You don't have to `join()` every time you do `replace()` as you will get a new string.

Also, once you `split()` a string you get an array, so you need to `join()` to get another string and then `split()` again for the second word.

Please check the working demo.

```js
function BoiFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById('myText').value; 
  var output = document.getElementById('demo');
  var garbageWords = str.split(',').join('').split('by').join('');
  output.innerHTML = garbageWords;
  var garbageWords2 = str.replace(/,/g,'').replace(/by/g,'');
  document.getElementById('demoWithReplace').innerHTML = garbageWords2;
}
```

```html
<p align="center"><input type="text" id="myText" 
 placeholder="Definition"></p>
<p align="center"><button class="button-three" onclick="BoiFunction()"><p 
 align="center">boii </p></button></p>
 <font color="black">With Split: <p align="center" id="demo"></p></font>
 <font color="black">With Replace: <p align="center" id="demoWithReplace"></p></font>
```